# Deploying a C# application using LocalDB database

Tags: c#, sql-server, mdf

When I run my C# application on another PC, a network-related error appears. On my PC, it runs fine. I have used `AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|` to specify the location of my `.mdf` files. Now, what am I missing in this deployment that makes the application not to run on other PCs?

Comment: Did you install the localdb libraries?

Comment: Thanks for quick response..Steve do I install the SQL server ? Clarify please

Comment: What editor you using, did you created Setup.exe program,  how you managing sqlserver database (EntityFramework or sqlcommand executequey), WPF or WinForms  please specify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing an SQL Server instance on your client machines,one option is to install LocalDB on them. Find the installation file SqlLocalDB.MSI, suitable for OS versions on your client machines, you may try this latest version https://download.microsoft.com/download/7/c/1/7c14e92e-bdcb-4f89-b7cf-93543e7112d1/SqlLocalDB.msi

Comment: Thanks Errdonald for the quick response. Now, after installing the LocalDB on client's machine, do I need to modify any connection strings in my codes or that is just enough. Is it that the LocalDB instance installed will be able to connect to the .mdf files automatically whether they are in the application .exe folder or somewhere else?

Comment: Please, it's your privilege to accept my answer, I can't do it!
https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers